# How can I have stack-unwinding while using Structrured Exception Handling

Tags: winapi

How can I have stack-unwinding while using Structrured Exception Handling ?

I'm gonna ask my question after that because I've found a way to do that at least at a syntactical level and I thought this might be useful for others.

Comment: If using MSVC I suggest that you take a look at _set_se_translator. It allows you to transform SEH exception values into C++ exception objects.

Comment: The translator function would be similar to my filter-function. But this has to be a C-function so I couln't use any function-objects with a capture anymore. So I would have to make the accesed variables outside the filter function scope static or thread_local.

Comment: *"Unwinding the stack"* has very different meanings when talking about SEH and C++ exception handling. In case of SEH local non-static variables get cleared from the stack. And that is all that's happening. Contrast that with C++ exception handling that, in addition, runs destructors of local non-static objects. Which *"stack unwinding"* is this question asking about?

Comment: @IInspectable: Eh, ... you might read from my answer that I know this and that I found a way to combine normal SEH exception handling with C++ exception handling inside the "same" (syntactically) function.

Comment: This isn't about what *you* know or don't know. It is about making the question useful to future visitors. As currently written it is at least ambiguous, if not straight up unclear. And while there is no language tag it's not even clear what unwind semantics the question is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to have stack unwinding while using Structured Exception Handling.
The following code catches an I/O error while using a memory-mapped file:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

using XHANDLE = unique_ptr<void, decltype([]( void *h ) { h && h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE && CloseHandle( (HANDLE)h ); })>;
using XMAP_VIEW = unique_ptr<void, decltype([]( void *p ) { p && UnmapViewOfFile( p ); })>;

template<typename Fn, typename Filter, typename Handler>
    requires requires( Fn fn, Filter filter, EXCEPTION_POINTERS *pEp, Handler handler ) { { fn() }; { filter( pEp ) } -> same_as<LONG>; { handler() }; }
void seh_encapsulate( Fn fn, Filter filter, Handler handler );

int wmain( int argc, wchar_t **argv )
{
    if( argc < 2 )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    XHANDLE xhFile( CreateFileW( argv[1], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL ) );
    if( xhFile.get() == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    LARGE_INTEGER liFileSize;
    if( !GetFileSizeEx( xhFile.get(), &liFileSize ) || liFileSize.QuadPart > (size_t)-1 )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    XHANDLE xhMappging( CreateFileMapping( xhFile.get(), nullptr, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, nullptr ) );
    if( !xhMappging.get() )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    XMAP_VIEW mapView( MapViewOfFile( xhMappging.get(), FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0 ) );
    if( !mapView.get() )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    atomic_char
        *pa = (atomic_char *)mapView.get(),
        *paEnd = pa + (size_t)liFileSize.QuadPart;
    seh_encapsulate(
            [&]()
            {
                for( ; ; )
                    for( atomic_char *paScn = pa; paScn != paEnd; ++paScn )
                        (void)paScn->load( memory_order_relaxed );
            },
            [&]( EXCEPTION_POINTERS *pEp ) -> LONG
            {
                if( pEp->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode != EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR )
                    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
                if( pEp->ExceptionRecord->NumberParameters < 2 )
                    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
                void *where = (void *)pEp->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation[1];
                if( where < pa || where >= paEnd )
                    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
                return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
            },
            []()
            {
                cout << "I/O error" << endl;
            } );
}

template<typename Fn, typename Filter, typename Handler>
    requires requires( Fn fn, Filter filter, EXCEPTION_POINTERS *pEp, Handler handler ) { { fn() }; { filter( pEp ) } -> same_as<LONG>; { handler() }; }
void seh_encapsulate( Fn fn, Filter filter, Handler handler )
{
    __try
    {
        fn();
    }
    __except( filter( GetExceptionInformation() ) )
    {
        handler();
    }
}
```

The trick with that is to have the code with the SEH-exception to be called, the filter- and the handler-function to be function objects of seh_encapsulate. seh_encapsulate normally won't be inlined since for the compiler it needs to be code with a separate function body since it uses Structured Exception Handling. The code of the "Function" object mustn't use any stack unwinding since the thrown exception from inside that might bypass any object destruction. But the "Filter" object as well as the "Handler" object can have stack unwinding. And the surrounding code of seh_encapsulate can have stack unwinding as well.
So at least at a syntatical level it looks like you have Structured Exception Handling in a function that has object unwinding.

Comment: Mixing C++ exception handling and SEH exception handling is not ever a good idea. Might want to consider using something that's `noexcept` in place of `std::cout`'s `operator<<`.

Comment: streams never throw if they're not instructed to to that. C++ exception handling and SEH exception handling base on the same unwinding-facilities, so it doesn't hurt that there would be unwinding code for the calling code of operator << as long as there's no exception actually being thrown.

Comment: Obviously, exceptions aren't thrown without them being thrown. Though that's not something *you* control. The library implementation makes that decision, and none of the [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) overloads are marked `noexcept`. Your compiler assumes that any of those operators can throw, and you would be well advised in agreeing with the compiler.

Comment: This absolutely doesn't matter as long as no exception is being thrown. streams throw exceptions only if they're configured to to that. cout is defaulted not to do that.

Comment: Obviously. But again, that's not something you decide nor control.

Comment: Where in my code am I doing sth. like cout.exceptions( ... ) ?

Comment: This is making assumptions about code you do not control. As written the assumption could be true, depending on the specific runtime used and/or compiler options. Feel free to ignore me and deal with minidumps later, that contain stack traces that are virtually impossible to parse by humans.

Comment: It's safe to make these assumptions here because streams are specified not to throw any exception until they're enforced to do that with streamName.exceptions( ... ).

Answer (score 0):

IInspectable pointed out that `operator <<` could throw an exception. I argued that this won't happen and if this would happen for other reasons the lambda would be compiled into a separate function being called from my seh_encapsulate.
I just checked that with the following example code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    __try
    {
        char const *outer = "world";
        [&]()
        {
            string inner( "hello" );
            inner += " ";
            inner += outer;
            cout << inner << endl;
        }();
    }
    __except( EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER )
    {
    }
}
```

If you run the code as a release-compile in the debugger you can see that the lambda gets called separately:

```
lea         rax,[outer]  
mov         qword ptr [rsp+20h],rax  
lea         rcx,[rsp+20h]  
call        `main'::`3'::<lambda_1>::operator()
```

The above code inside the lambda might throw bad_alloc and has object unwinding as well.
So this discussion leaded to a sometimes simpler solution like that in my first answer and clarified some non-relevant issues.